# Auto expand EditText

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to make my Edittext autoexpand so that all the data the user has entered so far is visible at least up to 5 lines. However I also don't want my actionbar on top to disappear while doing this.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/CCLL"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#303e73"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".3">

    <ListView
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:background="#26315c"
        android:id="@+id/messagesLV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>

</LinearLayout>




<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="#303e73"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/addimgbtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:background="#303e73"
        android:src="@mipmap/whiteadd" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageET"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:minHeight="120dp"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="Enter your Message..." />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sendbtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:background="#303e73"
        android:src="@mipmap/whitesend" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="5" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
```

Comment: It just put moves the text to the top of the Edittext which is not visible

Answer (score 1):

By increasing `android:lines` you can define expand it how many lines.